# Rails round method dont give's me what I want

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, controller, rounding

I have a problem with the round method. When I round a number like 1.876 it give me just 1.8 and I need to have 1.80 I use round(2).

My function is like:

```
@number.attr = (((@number1.to_f*number2.to_f)/100.0)).round(2).to_s
```

Answer (score 1):

Round can't do that because 1.8 is a standard float but 1.80 is not a standard float.

```
irb(main)> 1.80.to_f
=> 1.8
```

The solution is to concatenate your result string with a zero if there is only 1 number after the '.'

Answer (score 0):

```
1.9.3-p194 :001 > sprintf("%.2f", 1.8)
# => "1.80" 
1.9.3-p194 :002 > sprintf("%.2f", 1.876)
# => "1.88"
```